# App crash when I try to open Main2Activity with FloatingActionButton

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    final FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(fab.getContext(), Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

I tried too much times different ways but I am a new developer.

Comment: Look at [the stack trace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173) to determine the cause of the crash.

Comment: show the code for Main2Activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_my_icon"
        android:layout_margin="16dp" />


  FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContex(), Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

This is work for me maybe helps you.